# Formatting Sqlite table to string (char) in C?

Tags: c, sqlite, file, format

I'm really new to Sqlite and I want to write a text file (xml actually) from an sqlite database table automatically using C. How can I do that? I got these to select some data from database and print in terminal:

```
int callback(void * ptr, int resultados, char ** STR1, char **STR2) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; STR1[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s = %s\n", STR2[i], STR1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and inside of main:

```
/* Open database */
   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      exit(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }

   /* Create SQL statement */
   sql = "SELECT * from COMPANY";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
```

and then I tried to change the callback, to get STR1 and STR2 to write a text file, something like this:

```
int callback(void * ptr, int resultados, char ** STR1, char **STR2) {
   int i;
   char teste[1024];
   FILE *pFile;

   pFile = fopen ("test.txt", "a+");
   for(i = 0; STR1[i] != NULL; i++) {
       printf("%s = %s\n", STR2[i], STR1[i]);
       snprintf (teste, sizeof(teste), "%s %s\n", STR2[i], STR1[i]);
       fwrite (teste, 1, sizeof(teste), pFile);
       fflush(pFile);

   }
   return 0;
}
```

but when I try to open the test.txt, gedit says 'There was a problem opening the file /home/kdan/test/test.txt. The file you opened has some invalid characters', and the text contains a bunch of random characters, numbers and symbols. So I'm not being able to get the selected data and convert to string D: should I try to use something like `sqlite_mprintf`, `sqlite_vmprintf`, `sqlite_exec_printf` or `sqlite_get_table_printf`? Would it be right? Or is there another way to select the data and format it to a variable `char`? Sorry for my rusty english.

Edited: It is working now, just needed to use fputs instead of fwrite, here is the code working:

```
int callback(void * ptr, int resultados, char ** STR1, char **STR2) {
   int i;
   char teste[1024];
   FILE *pFile;
   pFile = fopen ("test.txt", "a");
    for(i = 0; STR1[i] != NULL; i++) {
       printf("%s = %s\n", STR2[i], STR1[i]);
       snprintf (teste, sizeof(teste), "%s %s\n", STR2[i], STR1[i]);
       fputs (teste, pFile);
       fflush(pFile);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: actually `sqlite3_snprintf()` its probably what I need right? It's hard for me to find good content to me because there is none in my language D:

Comment: Maybe `fwrite (teste, 1, strlen(teste), pFile);` as `teste` is not fully initialized.   or simply `fputs(teste, pFile)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested your code but I think the problem is with the `fwrite()` call.

From the linux manpages:

```
NAME
       fread, fwrite - binary stream input/output

SYNOPSIS
       [...]

       size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
                     FILE *stream);

DESCRIPTION
       [...]

       The  function  fwrite()  writes nmemb elements of data, each size bytes
       long, to the stream pointed to by stream, obtaining them from the loca‐
       tion given by ptr.
```

`STR2[i]` and `STR1[i]` may have a total length less than `sizeof teste`. For illustrative purpose, let's say `STR2[i]` is `"foo"` and `STR1[i]` is `"bar"`. After the `snprintf()` call, `teste` will have the following contents:

```
teste[0] 'f'
teste[1] 'o'
teste[2] 'o'
teste[3] ' '
teste[4] 'b'
teste[5] 'a'
teste[6] 'r'
teste[7] '\n'
teste[8] '\0'
teste[9] onwards uninitialised
```

Since `fwrite` is for writing to a binary stream, it will NOT stop writing after reaching the `'\0'` byte. Instead it will keep writing all the uninitialised characters in `teste`. In this case it will write 1015 uninitialised characters.

The proper way to write to a text stream is to use either `fputs()` (in which case you should remove the `'\n'` in your string) or `fprintf()`. Or, if you really want to use `fwrite()`, ask it to print `strlen(teste)` bytes (which will be 8 in this case) instead of `sizeof teste` which is 1024.

Finally, although not related to your problem, if you are not reading from the file you should `fopen()` it with `"a"` instead of `"a+"`.

Comment: The fputs worked! I feel so dumb for posting it now lol and btw, when I used `strlen` instead of `sizeof` it gives me an warning when I try to compile it -> `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strlen' [enabled by default]` , so I'm still using `sizeof` instead of `strlen`and still, it's working, thank you very much! I'm posting the code working on the question.

Comment: and i forgot to tell, I'm also still using the `'\n'` and no problems :D

Comment: `strlen()` requires the `string.h` header. If you want to use it you need to add `#include <string.h>` at the beginning of your source code.